# Unstable wireless in Ubuntu 14.10

Tags: wireless, networking, intel-wireless, 14.10

After the upgrade to Ubuntu 14.10, my wireless connection has become unstable.
In every 2 to 3 minutes the network stops working (i.e., I am unable to load any page), even though the Network Manager, shows that I am connected.
So I have to manually disconnect it and connect it again,to make it work again, but then again it only works for another 2-3 minutes.

I'm using a Dell Inspiron 7357, with a `Intel Corporation Wireless 7260 (rev 73)` card. With Ubuntu 14.04, the adapter worked perfectly.

I don't see neither crashes nor errors in `dmesg`:

```
$ dmesg | grep iw
[    3.636727] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: irq 62 for MSI/MSI-X
[    3.709654] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: loaded firmware version 25.222.9.0 op_mode iwlmvm
[    3.742636] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Wireless N 7260, REV=0x144
[    3.743790] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: L1 Enabled; Disabling L0S
[    3.744023] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: L1 Enabled; Disabling L0S
[    3.940407] ieee80211 phy0: Selected rate control algorithm 'iwl-mvm-rs'
[    4.863737] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: L1 Enabled; Disabling L0S
[    4.863967] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: L1 Enabled; Disabling L0S
```

Of course, I don't have any problem if I select the old 3.13 kernel in Grub (in that case, the firmware version is the .8). Do you have any ideas?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Wifi losing connection, weak signal, Intel 7260 adapter](http://askubuntu.com/questions/660155/wifi-losing-connection-weak-signal-intel-7260-adapter)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try this following workaround:

1. Open the terminal: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd>
2. `sudo modprobe -r iwlwifi`
3. `sudo modprobe iwlwifi 11n_disable=1`

Case this solved the problem, so...

1. `sudo nano /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf`
2. add the line: `options iwlwifi 11n_disable=1`
3. Save file
4. Restart the PC.

Case you have any problem, please comment.

Comment: Would it disable the fastest 802.11n standard?

Comment: Unfortunately this module works partially in some wireless adapters. You can try update the kernel. Perform `uname -a`and paste on a comment your kernel version.

Comment: @MarcosRocha Unfortunately,unless you amend the .conf file, the parameter 11n_disable=1 will go away on reboot.

Comment: sorry, I edited my answer with how to make that permanent.

Comment: `$ uname -a`
`Linux inspiron 3.16.0-24-generic #32-Ubuntu SMP Tue Oct 28 13:07:32 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

Comment: Cerrigno, I don't have many options to you. The newest stable kernel is the 3.17, so I think that a kernel upgrade will not help you.

Comment: The option `11n_disable=1` does not work for me. After it, it's impossible to connect again to the network, and I need to reboot.