# Wifi losing connection, weak signal, Intel 7260 adapter

Tags: wireless, drivers, intel-wireless, iwlwifi

I yesterday upgraded from Windows to Ubuntu 15.04 but I have problem with my wireless adapter Intel Corporation Wireless 7260 (rev 73). It randomly loses internet connection. Restarting adapter always helps. (same it did with Windows, except that sometimes restarting adapter didn't help).

Additionally, I have weaker connection then I had with Windows. 
Thank you!

Comment: Please, specify your hardware in the body of the question. Is this Zenbook or Lenovo?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can try this option. Run in terminal

```
sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi-opt.conf <<< "options iwlwifi 11n_disable=1"
```

and reboot.

If this does not help, some other options can be used.

It looks like this adapter does not work well in 802.11n mode. So disabling it improves connection.

There are some other options, that may be tuned.

```
power_save=0
bt_coex_active=0
swcrypto=1
```

You can also try to disable not all 802.11n, but partially. It can be selected by `11n_disable=2`, `11n_disable=4` or `11n_disable=8` instead of `11n_disable=1`.

You can apply them the same way as with `11n_disable=1`. You can use any combination of these options, e.g.

```
sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi-opt.conf <<< "options iwlwifi power_save=0 swcrypto=1"
```

You can enable all of them and remove one by one to test which one does the trick.

Every new setting overwrites the previous one.

To completely remove the options, remove `/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi-opt.conf` by running

```
sudo rm /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi-opt.conf
```

***Please do not forget to comment on which options worked for you.***

Explanation of the options can be found by

```
 modinfo iwlwifi | grep parm
```

Comment: This will disable 802.11n, right?

Comment: Yes, it will. But it is revertable. Try it first.

Comment: Intresting, it looks, that signal is better!

Comment: Thank you! How is it possible? Is there any solution without disabling wifi N?

Comment: I updated the answer. You can try others.

Comment: I will try other, but probably disabling N is not a problem, since most serevrs won't let me download more then 10 Mb/s

Comment: What does those options do?

Comment: First - powersave, second - BT and WiFi at once, third - disabling HW encryption?

Comment: I would try as I wrote first. Powersave and encryption. If you do not use bluetooth, it is unlikely may cause problems. All use just all of them.

Comment: I fixed this before under Ubuntu 15.04 or maybe 14.10 by adding the line ``options iwlwifi 11n_disable=1`` to ``/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf``. That didn't work anymore after the 15.10 upgrade, so I tried your solution, which seems to work. How come the filename has changed to ``iwlwifi-opt.conf``?

Comment: File name makes no difference. You can add it to the original `iwlwifi.conf`. I made a new file to keep the old one.

Comment: @YanickNedderhoff i only have `iwlwifi.conf` on 15.10 .   no `iwlwifi-opt.conf` . BTW it works

Comment: No one has `iwlwifi-opt.conf` in any distro. I made a new file with this command to keep the default `iwlwifi.conf`.

Answer (score 0):

I changed the channel wifi from 100 to 36 and the wifi card start to run again, other clients wifi mac had no issues with 100 and 36

Lenovo t440p 
K 3.19.0-42-generic 
U 15.04 64-bit
Intel Corporation Wireless 7260 (rev 83)
Firmware 25.17.12.0
linux-firmware  Version  1.143.7 
lib/firmware/iwlwifi-7260-12.ucode

Answer (score 0):

With firmware `iwlwifi-7260-ucode-25.17.12.0`, 
On an HP Pavilion g4, 10 ft. away from the Wifi router:

```
Link Quality=47/70  Signal level=-63 dBm,
```

while the same distance on a Raspberry Pi Zero W:

```
Link Quality=70/70  Signal level=-34 dBm
```

I would expect much better!