# Broadcom BCM43142 driver

Tags: networking, wireless, drivers, broadcom

This is a continuation of [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/663116/broadcom-wireless-driver-not-working).
One answer said that the driver for the Broadcom BCM43142 wifi chip has "not been released into the mainstream yet".
Does anyone know when it will become available?