# Lose wifi connections Intel Corporation Wireless 7260

Tags: 14.04, networking, intel-wireless, iwlwifi

Sometimes after I wake the computer after suspend/hibernation, I cant get Wifi to work. It has happened in Ubuntu 14.04, Linux Mint (and Windows 10).

I have seen multiple treads about problems with the Intel 7260, but I can't seem to find any answers that work.

The kernel drive is iwlwifi

I have tried what is suggested here ([Wifi losing connection, weak signal, Intel 7260 adapter](https://askubuntu.com/questions/660155/wifi-losing-connection-weak-signal-intel-7260-adapter)), but it didn't work. Any other suggestion? I need my wifi to work all the time, not just sometimes.

Comment: I had similar problems with ubuntu, it can affect both windows and ubuntu apparently, I don't know what happens but it's like ubuntu is locking the network card. Have you tried to reinstall the drivers for the card in ubuntu ?
This card was already in your computer when you installed ubuntu ?

Comment: That is your ethernet card. Please edit your question to add details of your wireless from the terminal command: `lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A2`

Comment: It is not a Realtek, but Intel. Realtek is your Ethernet adapter.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Wifi losing connection, weak signal, Intel 7260 adapter](http://askubuntu.com/questions/660155/wifi-losing-connection-weak-signal-intel-7260-adapter)

Comment: Looked at that tread and tried it all. Nothing worked, sadly