# (duplicate / resolved) Lenovo yoga 2 pro, 7260, wifi : help

Tags: iwlwifi

[resolved] [duplicate]
I'm a Ubuntu 15.04 vivid 64 bits user
I've got so many problem since 15.04 with my wifi, so boring :(
Connection is unstable, dropping packet, losing connection after auto suspend, etc...
On boot, WiFi seams correct, but after some times (irregular) it gone away. Often, status bar tells me "Wifi is not ready" or "wifi is deactivated" (no physical button...)

Please some help will be great
Some information below:

```
lspci -k -nn | grep -A 3 -i net 

01:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wireless 7260
[8086:08b1] (rev bb)    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Dual Band
Wireless-AC 7260 [8086:c070]    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi


sudo rfkill list 
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
2: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

My dmesg is full of

```
[ 9330.808954] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: L1 Disabled - LTR Disabled
[ 9330.948660] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: L1 Disabled - LTR Disabled
[ 9336.755375] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Failed to load firmware chunk!
[ 9336.755388] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Could not load the [0] uCode section
[ 9336.755392] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Failed to start RT ucode: -110
[ 9338.558578] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Failing on timeout while stopping DMA channel 0 [0x5a5a5a5a]
[ 9340.378335] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Failing on timeout while stopping DMA channel 2 [0x5a5a5a5a]
[ 9342.231506] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Failing on timeout while stopping DMA channel 5 [0x5a5a5a5a]
[ 9344.049952] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Failing on timeout while stopping DMA channel 7 [0x5a5a5a5a]
[ 9330.808954] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: L1 Disabled - LTR Disabled
[ 9330.948660] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: L1 Disabled - LTR Disabled
[ 9336.755375] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Failed to load firmware chunk!
[ 9336.755388] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Could not load the [0] uCode section
[ 9336.755392] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Failed to start RT ucode: -110
[ 9338.558578] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Failing on timeout while stopping DMA channel 0 [0x5a5a5a5a]
[ 9340.378335] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Failing on timeout while stopping DMA channel 2 [0x5a5a5a5a]
[ 9342.231506] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Failing on timeout while stopping DMA channel 5 [0x5a5a5a5a]
[ 9344.049952] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Failing on timeout while stopping DMA channel 7 [0x5a5a5a5a]
```

I have blacklisted ideapad_laptop in `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf`

I don't have a `/etc/modprobe.d/iwlmvm.conf` as I want to use Wifi 11N...

I'm using `/lib/firmware/iwlwifi-7260-13.ucode` (cheating the OS renaming it .10)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Wifi losing connection, weak signal, Intel 7260 adapter](http://askubuntu.com/questions/660155/wifi-losing-connection-weak-signal-intel-7260-adapter)

Comment: Thank you Pilot6.

I just try power_save=0 in a new file /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi-opt.conf
I want to keep N and HW encryption is possible...
Will stay in touch. The wireless module is a new one I brought and install in my enovo yago 2 pro (to avoid problem...but no chance...)

Comment: THANKS @Pilot6
It seems after a night my connecion is still there !!
But really, I don't understand why such a bug is still present is such a widely sell wifi component !
I will keep a eye for some days and will mark my question as answered

Comment: You can also try `14` firmware. And it is wrong to rename it to `10`. It will not be used this way, if `12` is present. Rename it to `12`. This halped one user. Maybe you will not need to remove powersave. If that works, please write it as an answer and accept it. I will bookmark it and direct other similar questions to this answer.

Comment: iwlwifi-7260-14 is not present for me (only 13)
I run  (uname -a) Linux yoga 3.19.0-28-generic #30-Ubuntu SMP Mon Aug 31 15:52:51 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: You can download 14 and 15 from here. https://github.com/OpenELEC/iwlwifi-firmware/tree/master/firmware

Comment: I will try this evening and tell you. Thanks @Pilot6

Comment: version 13 and 15 doesn't work for me (on 3.19.0-30-generic)
A "dmseg | grep iwl" indicate "Driver unable to support your firmware API. Driver supports v12, firmware is v0."

Comment: So mark this as a duplicate.