# No internet connection on 14.04LTS + Thinkpad x250

Tags: wireless

I received my laptop (Thinkpad x250) today, installed Ubuntu 14.04 LTS 64-bit on it, but don't have a Wi-Fi internet connection. My Wi-Fi is working, because I am now writing this. How could I make it work on Linux?

This is the output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2`:

```
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wireless 7265 [8086:095b] (rev 59)
Subsystem: Intel Corporation Dual Band Wireless-AC 7265 [8086:5210]
Kernel driver in use; iwlwifi
```

Internet is working on all my home devices (smartphone, and this laptop) but not on my new laptop. I see my network available in the menu bar, but can't connect to it. If i click it it searches for internet, and after a while it complains: `Disconnected - you are now offline`.
And @terdon this is the output of `iwconfig`:

```
eth0    no wireless extensions.

wlan0   IEEE 802.11abgn ESSID:off/any
        Mode:Managed Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=22 dBm
        Retry short limit:7  RTS thr:off    Fragment thr:off
        Power Management:on

lo      no wireless extensions.
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2` terminal command.

Comment: @Pilot6 the OP edited as requested. Amir, where is your WiFi working? Under a different operating system like Windows? What happens when you try to connect? Do you see no networks available? Can you see the network but can't connect to it? Can you connect but have no internet access? Please [edit] and clarify.

Comment: @terdon It is now working on all my home devices (smartphone, and this laptop) but not on my new laptop. I see my network available in the menu bar, but can't connect to it. If i click it it searches for internet, and after a while it complains: `Disconnected - you are now offline`

Comment: Excellent, please *[edit]* your question and include this information. ALso, when editing, clarify whether you can i) not connect to the nwetwork or ii) connect but have no internet access (they are two separate things). You should also include the output of `iwconfig` after attempting to connect.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Wifi losing connection, weak signal, Intel 7260 adapter](http://askubuntu.com/questions/660155/wifi-losing-connection-weak-signal-intel-7260-adapter)

Comment: `sudo dmesg | tail` after you attempt to connect will be useful.

Comment: @Braiam no, this also didn't help

Comment: It would not fix anything but allow us to figure out the problem.

Comment: @Pilot6 why is this a duplicate? In this question the connection is unsuccessful, as far as OP points out.

Comment: Now the answer is updated and contains the solution.

Comment: @Braiam this is the output of  `sudo dmesg | tail` : because its too long, i send it it 2 parts. @Pilot6 i have already tried the other pot, didn't help. By the way a silly question: could it be that the internet server cant find the second device if both have the same username? both amir@thinkpad...

Comment: `[  174.254428] wlan0: 34:81:c4:c7:fb:06 denied authentication (status 37)
[  175.292155] wlan0: authenticate with 34:81:c4:c7:fb:07
[  175.299697] wlan0: send auth to 34:81:c4:c7:fb:07 (try 1/3)
[  175.309485] wlan0: 34:81:c4:c7:fb:07 denied authentication (status 37)
[  179.659975] wlan0: authenticate with 34:81:c4:c7:fb:06
[  179.667027] wlan0: send auth to 34:81:c4:c7:fb:06 (try 1/3)
[  179.674142] wlan0: 34:81:c4:c7:fb:06 denied authentication (status 37)`

Comment: `[  189.725105] wlan0: authenticate with 34:81:c4:c7:fb:07
[  189.732251] wlan0: send auth to 34:81:c4:c7:fb:07 (try 1/3)
[  189.742061] wlan0: 34:81:c4:c7:fb:07 denied authentication (status 37)`

Comment: Always edit your question adding the new information. Is the password correct and your system near the base? Is WEP or WPA/2?

Comment: my laptop is actually not near to the base,  and it is WPA/WPA2

Comment: Please [run the WiFi diagnostics](/a/425205/175814) and [edit] your question to include a link to the result. The currently provided diagnostics are a good start, but the diagnosis script in the linked post covers many more things.

Comment: As a start, move the WiFi client close to the access point and try to authenticate there. Make sure, that the access key is correct. If there's still no success, try to disable WPA on the access point for a short while to test, if an association is possible at all. Provide the output of `sudo dmesg | tail` again, if no association is possible even without WPA.

Answer (score -1):

14.04 ships an old kernel. Please update your wifi driver / firmware.
Take a look at https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/drivers/iwlwifi/core_release

Comment: I recommend [edit]ing this answer to expand it with specific details about how to do this. (See also [How do I write a good answer?](/help/how-to-answer) for general advice about what sorts of answers are considered most valuable on Ask Ubuntu.)