# Wifi on Dell Latitude 3340 cannot be enabled after installing Ubuntu 15.10

Tags: wireless, dell, iwlwifi

I just installed Ubuntu 15.10 on my dell latitude 3340 and now i cannot enable wifi since it is greyed out. Is there anyone who can help me with this? Any help is much appreciated!

PS here is a link with additional info about my wifi: http://paste.ubuntu.com/12999579/

`dmesg | grep rename` results in:

```
[    1.308743] e1000e 0000:00:19.0 eno1: renamed from eth0
[    2.600819] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0 wlp3s0: renamed from wlan0
```

Comment: Please execute the statement `dmesg | grep rename` and append the results of this to your question.  I also had an issue with WiFi, and was able to resolve it, but it was not easy.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Wifi losing connection, weak signal, Intel 7260 adapter](http://askubuntu.com/questions/660155/wifi-losing-connection-weak-signal-intel-7260-adapter)

Comment: @Pilot6 I'm not sure this is a duplicate: for me, the same issue was the renaming of the wifi link that occurs during the boot processes.

Comment: The problems with this adapter can be solved the way it is answered to the other question.

Comment: The result of dmesg | grep rename is: [    1.308743] e1000e 0000:00:19.0 eno1: renamed from eth0
[    2.600819] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0 wlp3s0: renamed from wlan0

Comment: @user2351350 You could try the answer suggested by Pilot6, however this solution would not have worked for me (I am within 6 feet of the router; My signal strength is fine.  I will post an answer to this question in a short bit, with instructions for the fix that worked on my system

Comment: @Pilot6 I just tried the commands in the answer proposed by you (and rebooted after trying each of them) but the problem still remains..

Comment: @CharlesGreen I also do not think my problem has to do with wifi strength, but with the fact my wifi adapter just does not work with ubuntu at the moment, maybe a driver issue or something?

Comment: Working on the answer that helped for me...

Comment: about 2 minutes:  I do want to check for typos.  I assume this card worked properly in Ubuntu before 15.10?

Comment: @user2351350 Posted the answer - it's a fair bit of work, and will require two reboots.  You adaptors name prior to the renaming process is `wlan0`

Comment: @CharlesGreen This is the first ubuntu version i have installed on this device so i do not know if it works with other ubuntu versions.. But i'll try your answer and post the result here. Thanks for you effort

Comment: Should it fail, delete the file in rules.d and reboot:  `rm 70-persistent-net.rules`

Answer (score 2):

In my Dell 5521, the problem is related to renaming of the wireless adapter at boot time.

To prevent adapter renaming, I use a kernel parameter `net.ifnames=0`

Open a terminal window (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd>), and enter:

`sudo nano /etc/default/grub`

Change the line:

`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"`

to

`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash net.ifnames=0"`

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>o</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd> to save and exit, then enter

`sudo update-grub`
`sudo reboot`

Comment: I tried the first part of your answer, but i get stuck at the point where i need to execute the command `cat /sys/class/network/<wlan new name>/address` because i get the error `cat: /sys/class/network/wlp3s0/address: No such file or directory` I checked and there is indeed no network folder with that address, any idea what the cause of this may be?

Comment: Dang!  it should have been `/sys/class/net/wlp3s0/address` : I knew I should have triple checked the syntax!

Comment: I  did all the steps but there is still no change, the "enable wifi" setting is still greyed out.. Thanks for your help though! If you still have any ideas or a suggestion in what direction i can continue my search i would like to hear it :)

Comment: Stupid me - I should have looked harder at your question.  `rfkill list` which was in your pastebin, shows the wifi is turned off in the hardware (hard blocked: yes) - look for the switch on your keyboard, side of the computer, or in bios...  you will probably need to reboot, baased upon some of the things I've read.

Comment: Your wireless is showing `hard blocked:yes`. What is the position of the wireless switch on your laptop?

Comment: @CharlesGreen It was indeed a key i needed to press, thanks! I already saw a post which gave this answer, but it showed a picture of a laptop which had a dedicated button for that switch and mine does  not have such a button. But you answer made me think that it could be a key on my keyboard and that was the solution, so thanks again for all your efforts! Is there a way i can give credits to your answer for karma or something?

Comment: @user2351350 The last comment where I mentioned a key, you will find a small up-arrow next to it when you hover your mouse nearby - clicking on this gives me a small boost in reputation points.

Comment: @CharlesGreen Im pretty new to this forum but i think i do not have enough rep to upvote comments, is that possible? Because i can only delete comments as it seems, not upvote them..

Comment: Could be!  I'm glad that you have solved your problem though, and wish I had read your original post more closely.