# How can I make WiFi more stable on Ubuntu 15.10?

Tags: networking, wireless, drivers, 15.10, intel-nuc

**Hi!**

Before I begin describing the issue, let me mention that I tried following numerous suggestions,mostly revolving around disabling n mode and other options, as described in this one: [Wifi losing connection, weak signal, Intel 7260 adapter](https://askubuntu.com/questions/660155/wifi-losing-connection-weak-signal-intel-7260-adapter)

...and many others. Sadly it doesn't seem to help.

So I use Intel NUC5i3RYK. The wifi connection does not really disconnect, I can constantly see that it is connected (judging from the icon at least), but it just keeps being unstable: from time to time (like 2 times in every 5 minutes) the internet simply stops working - Skype and jabber (I use Pidgin) disconnect, I can't load any page etc. Then it comes back and the the circle starts over.

This is not a general issue with my WiFi itself, because I do not experience these issues on Windows or my Android mobile devices.

Details of the device:

> 02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wireless 7265
>   [8086:095a] (rev 59)  Subsystem: Intel Corporation Dual Band
>   Wireless-AC 7265 [8086:9010]  Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi

What else can I possibly do to solve it?

Thanks!

Comment: Please edit your question to add details of your wireless device: `lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A2` Also, on my NUC, many minor issues were solved when I updated the BIOS to the latest available. I recommend it if not already done.

Comment: Hi @chili555, as you requested I added the device specs. 
Also my BIOS is in the latest version, I updated it after I bought the device and started and started encountering issues.
Thanks for your response!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, check the settings in the router. WPA2-AES is preferred; not any WPA and WPA2 mixed mode and certainly not TKIP. Second, if your router is capable of N speeds, you may have better connectivity with a channel width of 20 MHz in the 2.4 GHz band instead of automatic 20/40 MHz, although it is likely to affect N speeds. I also have better luck with a fixed channel, either 1, 6 or 11, rather than automatic channel selection. Also, be certain the router is not set to use N speeds only; auto B, G and N is preferred. After making these changes, reboot the router.

Next, I recommend that your regulatory domain be set explicitly. Check yours:

```
sudo iw reg get
```

If you get 00, that is a one-size-maybe-fits-all setting. Find yours here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1_alpha-2 Then set it temporarily:

```
sudo iw reg set IS
```

Of course, substitute your country code if not Iceland. Set it permanently:

```
gksudo gedit /etc/default/crda
```

Use nano or kate or leafpad if you don't have the text editor gedit.

Change the last line to read:

```
REGDOMAIN=IS
```

Proofread carefully, save and close the text editor.

Next, I'd set IPv6 to Ignore in Network Manager: http://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora/18/html/Installation_Guide/images/netconfig/network-connections-ipv6-ignore.png  This example is for ethernet, but you want wireless.

Next, I am interested in which firmware version is being loaded. Reboot and run:

```
dmesg | grep iwl
```

Post the results that relate to firmware.

It appears that the driver finds and loads the -13 firmware but would use the later -14 or -15 if available. With a working internet connection, please do:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install git
git clone https://github.com/OpenELEC/iwlwifi-firmware.git
cd linux-firmware/firmware
sudo cp iwlwifi-7265D-14.ucode  /lib/firmware
sudo cp iwlwifi-7265D-15.ucode  /lib/firmware
```

Reboot and check:

```
dmesg | grep firmware
```

Ideally, the -15 firmware is loaded and performance is greatly improved.

Comment: I followed your suggestions and I can see an improvement. Thank you :).
What I did:

Security setting is 'WPA2 (CCMP)', which I think is OK.
I set the channel to 6 (was auto before).  Don't think I can set frequency to 20MHz (no such option). I can set WLAN type - I can choose from 802.11 n+g+b, n+g and b+g. I kept n+g+b.

Then I did the iw reg set, as suggested (was indeed 00). Changed to DE as I live in Germany. Worked just fine, so I set it permanently. Afterwards I also switched IPv6 to be ignored for wifi.

Comment: After a router reboot I used the dmesg | grep iwl command. Will post the outcome in separate comments, as it won't fit into a single one.

Comment: [    6.884491] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[    6.887379] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Unsupported splx structure
[    6.893701] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-7265D-15.ucode failed with error -2
[    6.894691] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-7265D-14.ucode failed with error -2
[    6.915548] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: loaded firmware version 25.30.13.0 op_mode iwlmvm
[    6.948476] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless AC 7265, REV=0x210

Comment: [    6.949479] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[    6.950078] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[    7.036744] ieee80211 phy0: Selected rate control algorithm 'iwl-mvm-rs'
[    7.829387] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[    7.830154] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[    7.891571] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[    7.892016] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled

Comment: [  119.970245] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[  119.970809] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[  120.033451] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[  120.033896] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled

Comment: [ 1674.285007] Modules linked in: ctr ccm nls_iso8859_1 drbg ansi_cprng dm_crypt arc4 intel_rapl iosf_mbi x86_pkg_temp_thermal intel_powerclamp coretemp kvm_intel kvm crct10dif_pclmul crc32_pclmul ghash_clmulni_intel iwlmvm aesni_intel mac80211 aes_x86_64 lrw gf128mul glue_helper ablk_helper cryptd serio_raw uvcvideo videobuf2_vmalloc input_leds videobuf2_memops snd_hda_codec_hdmi snd_hda_codec_realtek

Comment: snd_hda_codec_generic videobuf2_core iwlwifi v4l2_common videodev cfg80211 snd_soc_rt5640 media lpc_ich mei_me snd_hda_intel snd_soc_rl6231 snd_hda_codec snd_soc_core snd_hda_core snd_hwdep snd_compress ir_xmp_decoder mei shpchp ir_lirc_codec lirc_dev ac97_bus snd_pcm_dmaengine ir_mce_kbd_decoder ir_sharp_decoder ir_sanyo_decoder ir_sony_decoder ir_jvc_decoder ir_rc6_decoder ir_rc5_decoder ir_nec_decoder

Comment: [ 5586.425130] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[ 5586.425675] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[ 5586.487990] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[ 5586.488702] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled

Comment: Please see my edit above.

Comment: Hello @chili555, I tried doing that, but I'm stuck at cd linux-firmware/firmware command. When I try to use it, it says 'bash: cd: linux-firmware/firmware: No such file or directory', so I assume that it must have gone somewhere else :/.

Comment: Ah, found it, it went to /home/iwlwifi-firmware instead :). Trying again :).

Comment: OK, I'm getting this now: 
[    7.113029] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: loaded firmware version 15.195093.0 op_mode iwlmvm

I will test it now and will let you know!

Comment: In addition I also changed the channel to 11 and now it works like a charm! Thank you @chili555, I really appreciate your help!

Comment: Awesome! Glad it's working as expected. Have fun!